# Syntax of Maximum of $ax^2+bx+c$ in MAPLE

Tags: matlab, maple

I want to obtain a maximum value of an expression including parameter constants.
Can someone provide me the syntax in MAPLE for evaluating maximum of

1.$ax^2+bx+c$ where a,b,c are constants and x is variable.

2.$ax^2+bx+c$-dy where a,b,c,d are constants and x,y are variable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maximize(ax^2+bx+c);

Comment: Asking for *syntax* in a programming language is not a mathematics question. Your question should go on [StackOverflow under the Maple tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maple) instead.

Answer (score 0):

the result is $$\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & (b=0\land a=0)\lor (b=0\land a<0) \\
 \frac{4 a c-b^2}{4 a} & (b>0\land a<0)\lor (b<0\land a<0) \\
 \infty  & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,\left\{x\to 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{b}{2 a} & (b>0\land a<0)\lor (b<0\land a<0) \\
 0 & (b=0\land a=0)\lor (b=0\land a<0) \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: did you get this expression, in MAPLE? I am using MAPLE16 but is unable to get this result.

Comment: with Maple i get only $$\infty$$ as the result,one Moment please

Comment: i think in Maple 16 is this not possible

Comment: Can you provide any help, of finding this maximisation using Computers other than the manual process?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the [assume facility](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=assume) to make $a$, $b$ and $c$ constants and then use the `maximize` functional. The additional condition `x=-infinity..infinity` below translates to $x\in \mathbb R$ so as to avoid complex $x$.

```
assume(a::real,b::real,c::real);
maximize(a*x^2+b*x+c,x = -infinity..infinity) ;#assuming a>0;
```

Output:

> $
> \max \left( \operatorname{signum} \left( a\!\sim \right) \infty ,-1/4\,{\frac {{b\!\sim}^{2
> }}{a\!\sim}} \right) +c\!\sim
> $